# What does `class` do in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to understand what

```
class gcd = zero + one + dvd +
  fixes gcd :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a"
    and lcm :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a"
begin
```

from `GCD.thy` means. Browsing through Nipkow's [Programming and Proving](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/prog-prove.pdf) didn't reveal any example, that explains what `class` does, not did the [Tutorial on Isabelle/HOL](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjk1_Hnt5rSAhUsKsAKHdszDToQFggyMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fisabelle.in.tum.de%2Fdoc%2Ftutorial.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH3QiqZZWJq1-Cf_bwPBwNzZMlcEg).

Can you please explain to me what exactly `class` does ? I assume it defines a datatype. 
 Also, that fact that nothing follows after the last `+` seems irritating.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a datatype, but a Haskell-style type class. Isabelle's type class system is described in Florian Haftmann's [manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2016-1/doc/classes.pdf). The concept of [locales](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2016-1/doc/locales.pdf) is also closely related. Both are, I would say, advanced concepts in Isabelle that I would not recommend for a beginner to delve into. (which is also why the tutorials don't mention them)

To give you a brief overview: A type class is a way to talk about a collection of types that have something in common; for instance, the `ring` class talks about all types that form a ring: they have a `0` element, an addition and multiplication operation, and all of these fulfil certain laws. The `gcd` class you found is a type class for types that have a GCD and LCM defined on them (although it does not yet demand that these fulfil any laws; this is done in the `semiring_gcd` class.)

There *is* something after the final `+`: the `fixes`. The class declaration means that the class `gcd` is the intersection of the classes `zero` (type contains an element 0), the class `one` (contains a 1) and the class `dvd` (contains a notion of divisibility), and it additionally requires the presence of two functions `gcd` and `lcm`.

This class is a bit odd because it is purely *syntactic*, i.e. it does not require any laws to hold. Let's therefore also look at `semiring_gcd`:

```
class semiring_gcd = normalization_semidom + gcd +
  assumes gcd_dvd1 [iff]: "gcd a b dvd a"
    and gcd_dvd2 [iff]: "gcd a b dvd b"
    and gcd_greatest: "c dvd a ⟹ c dvd b ⟹ c dvd gcd a b"
    and normalize_gcd [simp]: "normalize (gcd a b) = gcd a b"
    and lcm_gcd: "lcm a b = normalize (a * b) div gcd a b"
```

This class requires the presence of a gcd/lcm (by being based on the `gcd` class) and the type has to be a `normalization_semidom` (see below). Then there are a number of assumptions that also need to be satisfied.

So, to summarise, type classes are a nice way of organising common properties and operation of types, but I'd say that for beginners, it's not really important to understand every detail of them in order to be able to *use* them.

---

**Bonus content:** (not terribly relevant, just for the curious)

If you're wondering about the `normalization_semidom` and `normalize`: This is a very technical thing. Basically, if you have several associated elements (like 1 and -1, or, with polynomials ℝ[X], X and 2X), you typically have some notion of which of these is the ‘canonical’ representative: if I asked you what the GCD of 2 and 3 is, you would probably say 1 and not -1, and if I asked what the GCD of 2X and X² ∈ ℝ[X] is, you would probably say X and not 2X.

Comment: Great explanantion! Do you perhaps also know, if a type class as you explained it is something that has a formal mathematical theory  in which it is grounded?  (I know that in ZF(C) in is not possible to speak formally of classes -only informally- but that there are other foundations of mathematics that explicitly allow classes. But I'm not sure how strongly the word "classes" as it is used in mathematics is related to its use in computer science as you explained it - or if the word "class" in computer science is only used informally and not formally like in maths.)

Comment: Type classes have absolutely nothing to do with classes in object-oriented programming or classes in set theory. As for mathematical foundation, there has been some recent work by Kunčar and Popescu showing that HOL + overloading (which includes type classes) is consistent w.r.t. ZFC. (Hope I didn't get anything wrong there): https://www21.in.tum.de/~kuncar/documents/kuncar-popescu-itp2015.pdf

Comment: frequently i found the isabelle syntax changes and *all* tutorials except `prog-prov` are using the old syntax which is not compatible to new versions, say isabelle-2016-1 :-(

Comment: What tutorials do you mean? All the manuals (like the classes manual I linked above should always be up to date. If they're not, please complain on the Isabelle users mailing list.